# Updating Large Amount Of Rows With Different Sets Of Columns More Efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have 10,000 rows I need to update in a MySQL table, and I need to update a different set of columns for each row (for example, some rows need the username changed, some rows need the phone number changed, and some rows need both changed). I need to be able to update these 10,000 rows in under 10 minutes, which presents the problem:

I am currently performing a separate update query for each row (using PDO), and it takes way too long to update 10,000 rows via 10,000 separate queries. I have used a "batch insert" before to speed up inserting 10,000 rows, but what can I do to speed things up performance-wise in the update department?

Comment: You might want to consider fetching all the rows, modifying them in PHP, then deleting and re-inserting the rows. Be sure to take a backup if you adopt this approach...

Comment: Hmmm... remarkably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554294/updating-different-columns-for-large-amount-of-rows

Comment: @Nick I thought about that, but the client says that's a no-go. Are you aware of any other options that can speed up the process?

Comment: Another option might be to write the new data (merged with old) to another table and then use a multi-table update query on the old table

Comment: Are you and tylerkmw working on the same project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554294/updating-different-columns-for-large-amount-of-rows

Comment: First, describe where the updates are coming from.  Do you have a list of usernames to change?  Are they in a table?  Perhaps some of the rows imply that no change is needed, or are there no such rows?  Or do you have a list of complete rows, _some_ columns of which are different?

Comment: And what key is used for matching a modification to an existing row?  Along with that, how many unique keys are there on the table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3):

There is basically no advantage to updating 1 or all columns in a record.  The overhead is in logging, locking, and managing the dirty data page -- and a data page generally contains multiple records.

If I assume that the none of the values are being updated to `NULL`, then you can create a table of updates that has:

- The primary key of the table being updated.
- non-`NULL` new values in columns whose values are changing.
- `NULL` values for columns that are not changing.

Then, the update looks like:

```
update original o join
       updates u
       on o.pk = u.pk
    set o.col1 = coalesce(u.col1, o.col1),
        o.col2 = coalesce(u.col2, o.col2),
        . . . ;
```

No `where` clause is needed because presumably every row in the `updates` table will have at least one non-`NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

10,000 rows in Mysql is nothing, especially if you use the PK (integer) in your where clause. The secret to fast update is proper indexing and use of the WHERE clause. If you need to update all rows, then you might just scan the entire table.